# Comparing the difference in means (group 1 v. group 2 and group 1 v. group 3)

Tags: hypothesis-testing, stata

I am a complete beginner in statistics. I have a database in Stata with data on people's cholesterol levels (continuous variable "cholesterol") and an indicator for whether the person is a vegetarian (binary variable "vegetarian"). Each person belongs to one of three groups (categorical variable "group", with possible values 1, 2 or 3). For each variable "cholesterol" and "vegetarian", I want to test:

1. Is the difference in mean/proportion between group 1 and group 2 **equal to the** difference in mean/proportion between group 1 and group 3?
2. Is the difference in mean/proportion between group 1 and group 2 **greater than** the difference in mean/proportion between group 1 and group 3?

I would like to know the appropriate two-sided and one-sided hypothesis test to use for difference in means/proportions when you have a continuous variable and a binary variable. If anyone has knowledge of Stata, I would also like to know how to run these tests.

Appreciate further guidance or advice for resources where I can read more on this!

Comment: Shall we assume that you want to test both (and independently) cholesterol levels and vegetarian status across the three groups, i.e. each of the hypotheses (1) and (2) subsume two tests?

Comment: Yes, I was thinking there will be two independent tests for each (1) and (2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common problem, so I will explain the general idea (otherwise this would be off-topic here), and then code it up in Stata. This assumes that you have a decent understanding of regression and hypothesis testing.

The basic idea is to take a two-sided test from a regression, which almost any software can do, and then manufacture a one-sided test out of that output. There are two ways of doing that. One is easy (divide the p-value by two), but doesn't always work (you need to flip the rules depending on the sign of the difference). The other is harder, but always works. There are also two variants of the hard one, depending on the type of two-sided test.

We will start by constructing a dataset of pig weights taken in weeks 1-3, 4-6, and 7-9. These will be our 3 groups. Pigs who are weighed in later weeks are on average heavier since they are older.

```
. /* (0) Data Step */
. webuse pig, clear
(Longitudinal analysis of pig weights)

. set seed 12032020

. egen group = cut(week), group(3) icodes

. replace group = group + 1
(432 real changes made)

. sample 1, by(id) count // sample a pig in a random week
(384 observations deleted)

. isid id

. table group, c(min week max week mean weight count id) 

------------------------------------------------------------------
    group |    min(week)     max(week)  mean(weight)         N(id)
----------+-------------------------------------------------------
        1 |            1             3      30.60714            14
        2 |            4             6      48.52941            17
        3 |            7             9      70.52941            17
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So we have 3 groups, with 48 pigs in total. Weight does seem to increase with group/age.

Now that we have the data, we can fit a regression:

```
. /* (1) Estimate Weight Model (Levels) */
. regress weight i.group

      Source |       SS           df       MS      Number of obs   =        48
-------------+----------------------------------   F(2, 45)        =    119.47
       Model |  12409.2683         2  6204.63413   Prob > F        =    0.0000
    Residual |  2337.05987        45  51.9346639   R-squared       =    0.8415
-------------+----------------------------------   Adj R-squared   =    0.8345
       Total |  14746.3281        47  313.751662   Root MSE        =    7.2066

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      weight |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       group |
          2  |   17.92227   2.600884     6.89   0.000     12.68382    23.16072
          3  |   39.92227   2.600884    15.35   0.000     34.68382    45.16072
             |
       _cons |   30.60714   1.926037    15.89   0.000     26.72791    34.48638
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. margins group, post // calculate average weight in each group

Adjusted predictions                            Number of obs     =         48
Model VCE    : OLS

Expression   : Linear prediction, predict()

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |            Delta-method
             |     Margin   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       group |
          1  |   30.60714   1.926037    15.89   0.000     26.72791    34.48638
          2  |   48.52941    1.74785    27.77   0.000     45.00906    52.04976
          3  |   70.52941    1.74785    40.35   0.000     67.00906    74.04976
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The `margins` command calculates the expect weight in each group from the regression output: group 3 is more than twice as heavy on average (70 kg) as group 1 (30 kg). Note that these averages match the simple summary statistics above.

To perform *one-sided* tests, you first perform the corresponding *two-sided* Wald test. Then you can use the results to calculate the test statistic and p-value for the one-sided test. So now we do the two-sided test on the averages: group 1 minus group 2 is equal to group 1 minus group 3. This can be accomplished like this:

```
. test (_b[1.group] - _b[2.group]) == (_b[1.group] -_b[3.group])

 ( 1)  - 2.group + 3.group = 0

       F(  1,    45) =   79.21
            Prob > F =    0.0000
```

We can see that the p-value is effectively zero (last row), so we reject the null that the two differences are equal. Note that Stata has simplified our hypothesis into testing that Group 3 and Group 2 have the same average weight, or that their difference is zero.

When the estimated difference is positive, you can calculate the one-sided p-values directly from the test output by dividing by two like this:

```
. display "p-value for H0: did <= 0 & Ha: did > 0 = " r(p)/2
p-value for H0: did <= 0 & Ha: did > 0 = 8.767e-12

. display "p-value for H0: did >= 0 & Ha: did < 0 = " 1-r(p)/2
p-value for H0: did >= 0 & Ha: did < 0 = 1
```

Here were would reject the null that the difference in differences (DID) is zero because the p-value is tiny (first line), but we cannot reject the null that the $\text{DID} \ge 0$ since the p-value is large (second line).

When the difference is negative, you will need to swap r(p)/2 and 1-r(p)/2 above.

Division by 2 is easy, but you can also do the following. The idea is that the Wald test given above is an F test with 1 numerator degree of freedom and 45 denominator degrees of freedom. The Student’s t distribution is related to the F distribution in that the square of the Student’s t distribution with d degrees of freedom is equivalent to the F distribution with 1 numerator degree of freedom and d denominator degrees of freedom. As long as the F test has 1 numerator degree of freedom, the square root of the F statistic (79.21) is the absolute value of the t statistic for the one-sided test. To determine whether this t statistic is positive or negative, you need to determine whether the difference is positive or negative. To do this, you can use the `sign()` function. So now we can get all the pieces we need and do the one-sided tests:

```
. /* Method (1) */
. scalar df = r(df_r)

. scalar Fstat = r(F)

. scalar sign_did = sign((_b[1.group] - _b[2.group]) - (_b[1.group] -_b[3.group]) - 0)

. display "p-value for H0: did <= 0 & Ha: did > 0 = " ttail(scalar(df),scalar(sign_did)*sqrt(scalar(Fstat)))
p-value for H0: did <= 0 & Ha: did > 0 = 8.767e-12

. display "p-value for H0: did >= 0 & Ha: did < 0= "  1-ttail(scalar(df),scalar(sign_did)*sqrt(scalar(Fstat)))
p-value for H0: did >= 0 & Ha: did < 0= 1
```

Note that this matches the division results we got above.

There is a somewhat more intuitive way that also demonstrates what to do when z statistics are reported instead of t statistics. In these cases, you will get a chi-squared test instead of an F test. The relationship between the standard normal distribution and the chi-squared distribution is similar to the relationship between the Student’s t distribution and the F distribution. In fact, the square root of the chi-squared distribution with 1 degree of freedom is the standard normal distribution. Therefore, one-sided z tests can be performed similarly to one-sided t tests:

```
. /* Method (2): More intuitive to me */
. nlcom did:(_b[1.group] - _b[2.group]) - (_b[1.group] -_b[3.group]) - 0, post

         did:  (_b[1.group] - _b[2.group]) - (_b[1.group] -_b[3.group]) - 0

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
         did |         22   2.471833     8.90   0.000      17.1553     26.8447
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. test did

 ( 1)  did = 0

           chi2(  1) =   79.21
         Prob > chi2 =    0.0000

. display r(p)/2
2.785e-19

. display 1-r(p)/2
1

. scalar sign_did = sign(_b[did] - 0)

. scalar chi2 = r(chi2)

. display "p-value for H0: did <= 0 & Ha: did > 0 = " 1 - normal(scalar(sign_did)*sqrt(scalar(chi2)))
p-value for H0: did <= 0 & Ha: did > 0 = 0

. display "p-value for H0: did >= 0 & Ha: did < 0 = " normal(scalar(sign_did)*sqrt(scalar(chi2)))
p-value for H0: did >= 0 & Ha: did < 0 = 1
```

I find this a bit more intuitive, since it returns the DID as if it was an estimation command, with all the "fixin's": we can see that the DID is 22, we get its standard error of 2.5, and also confidence interval that excludes zero. We know the sign and can also just do the division by zero.

For the binary outcome, you can use a `probit` or `logit` or just an LPM (a regression, but with het-robust errors). Everything after is the same as above. The output will generally be very similar.

```
logit binary_outcome i.group
margins group 
...
reg binary_outcome i.group, robust
margins group 
...
```

---

**Stata Code:**

```
clear
cls
/* (0) Data Step */
webuse pig, clear
set seed 12032020
egen group = cut(week), group(3) icodes
replace group = group + 1
sample 1, by(id) count // sample a pig in a random week
isid id
table group, c(min week max week mean weight count id) 

/* (1) Estimate Weight Model (Levels) */
/* Pigs who are weighed in later weeks should be heavier */
regress weight i.group
margins group, post // calculate average weight in each group

/* To perform one-sided tests, you can first perform the corresponding two-sided Wald test. */
/* Then you can use the results to calculate the test statistic and p-value for the one-sided test */
test (_b[1.group] - _b[2.group]) == (_b[1.group] -_b[3.group])
display "p-value for H0: did <= 0 & Ha: did > 0 = " r(p)/2
display "p-value for H0: did >= 0 & Ha: did < 0= " 1-r(p)/2
/* If difference is negative, you need to swap r(p)/2 and 1-r(p)/2 */

/* Method (1) */
scalar df = r(df_r)
scalar Fstat = r(F)
scalar sign_did = sign((_b[1.group] - _b[2.group]) - (_b[1.group] -_b[3.group]) - 0)
display "p-value for H0: did <= 0 & Ha: did > 0 = " ttail(scalar(df),scalar(sign_did)*sqrt(scalar(Fstat)))
display "p-value for H0: did >= 0 & Ha: did < 0 = "  1-ttail(scalar(df),scalar(sign_did)*sqrt(scalar(Fstat)))

/* Method (2): More intuitive to me */
nlcom did:(_b[1.group] - _b[2.group]) - (_b[1.group] -_b[3.group]) - 0, post
test did
display r(p)/2
display 1-r(p)/2
scalar sign_did = sign(_b[did] - 0)
scalar chi2 = r(chi2)
display "p-value for H0: did <= 0 & Ha: did > 0 = " 1 - normal(scalar(sign_did)*sqrt(scalar(chi2)))
display "p-value for H0: did >= 0 & Ha: did < 0 = " normal(scalar(sign_did)*sqrt(scalar(chi2)))
```

Comment: Thank you for such a clear explanation and code Dimitriy!

Comment: (+1) Nicely done.

Comment: Thank you both for the kind words. I think I finally understood one-sided testing in my early middle ages, so glad this is helping others.

Comment: Hi. Is there any non-parametric alternative to this? Something similar to Wilcoxon/Mann-Whitney tests? Thanks!

Comment: @amedicalenthusiast You can do a one-sided Wilcoxon, which is nonparametric. You just need to change the alternative to either less or greater since the default is typically two-sided.